# Unable to locate element in google drive preview mode using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, google-drive-api

**After automating the following steps:**

1. opening shared-link of the file in chrome which is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jUtvNE0bIJuRZwzll9xJbMxBuYIeh1mj/view
2. logging in with gmail

***I am stuck at locating the  connected apps section and opening the file with respective application, mostly the first one which is Google Colaboratory in my case.***

**I have tried using the following possible locator methods**

1. find_element_by_xpath
2. find_element_by_link_text
3. find_element_by_class_name

**For Instance:**

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ndfHFb-c4YZDc-rovI0b-DWWcKd-ibnC6b ndfHFb-c4YZDc-LgbsSe").click()
```

I there any possible solution for this?

Thank You.

Comment: witch element you are trying to press?

Answer (score 0):

Well the main thing to remember is to use CSS selectors. It's easy enough to get them - open the page source (F12 key on Windows, Chrome) and find the button you want interact with, right click it and press *Copy Selector*.

As I understand you are struggling with pressing the sign in button, so for you it would be

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-AHmuwe-Hr88gd-OWB6Me.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-vyDMJf-aZ2wEe.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-i5oIFb.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-TSZdd > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b > div > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b-AeOLfc-b0t70b > div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-mKZypf-bEDTcc > div").click()
```

While copying the selector path is not pretty, I use it because I don't have any web page knowledge so this helps a lot.

Next just to the same with every button.